# How do I fix Hyper-V Guest OS connectivity problems through RRAS/NAT?

Tags: networking, hyper-v, routing, nat, rras

I have a Hyper-V host machine with NAT set up for my guest virtual machine.  At a client site, the host connects to a wireless network through a cert (and then there's a proxy to access the extranet).

My guest machine can't access the extranet and is really slow to access internal pages.

If I do a ping or a tracert to google.com, it responds with ~40ms latency.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to isolate the guest from the various components.  For example, give it a public network adapter and see if that has the same issue.  If it does, then you know it's not your NAT device.  If it doesn't, then it's likely the NAT device and not related to the guest or Hyper-V.

In the tracert, you should see each hop and be able to tell which hop has the big jump.  Also, test against another machine in the same environment, and test against the host itself.  These will also help narrow down the single item that causes the ping time jump, then it will hopefully be easier to get to the root cause.